# Ruby on Rails MongoDB existing dataset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have a RoR application which will read info from a MongoDB collection.

I have my model set as:-

```
class Vulnerability
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :id, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :type, type: String
end
```

The first record in the collection is formatted like this:-

```
> db.vulnerabilities.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "NGINX:CVE-2009-3896",
    "_index" : "bulletins",
    "_type" : "bulletin",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
        "lastseen" : "2016-09-26T17:22:32",
        "references" : [ ],
        "edition" : 1,
        "description" : "Null pointer dereference vulnerability\nSeverity: major\nCVE-2009-3896\nNot vulnerable: 0.8.14+, 0.7.62+, 0.6.39+, 0.5.38+\nVulnerable: 0.1.0-0.8.13",
        "reporter" : "Nginx",
        "published" : "2009-11-24T12:30:00",
        "type" : "nginx",
        "title" : "Null pointer dereference vulnerability",
        "bulletinFamily" : "software",
        "affectedSoftware" : [
            {
                "name" : "nginx",
                "version" : "0.8.13",
                "operator" : "le"
            }
        ],
        "cvelist" : [
            "CVE-2009-3896"
        ],
        "modified" : "2009-11-24T12:30:00",
        "id" : "NGINX:CVE-2009-3896",
        "href" : "http://nginx.org/en/security_advisories.html",
        "cvss" : {
            "score" : 5,
            "vector" : "AV:NETWORK/AC:LOW/Au:NONE/C:NONE/I:NONE/A:PARTIAL/"
        }
    },
    "sort" : [
        38985
    ]
}
```

I want to pull the ID, the type and the description. When trying to view the index view I get 
`NameError at /vulnerabilities uninitialized constant Bulletin`

I believe the issue is with the `type` in the document as there is a key of `_type` but I want to get the type from the key _source, so in the example above it will display nginx not bulletin.

Comment: Yes, `_type` is something of reserved word in Mongoid as its used to store the document class. Easist option would be to alter the existing documents and change the `_type` field to `Vulnerability`.

Comment: The only issue with that is that's how the JSON file comes, which I don't have control over. Would it be better to scrap Mongo and just use MySQL? I have a MySQL DB for some other bits within the app

Comment: Surely you can normalize the incoming data before inserting it into mongodb? Mongodb does have some advantages if what you are storing is very dynamic.

Comment: The data is imported to MongoDB using a separate Python app

Comment: Then you're kind of skrewed as far as mongoid goes, I don't think the use  of the `_type` attribute is configurable. You might want to create an issue on github and ask the maintainers.

Comment: My only other option, as I see it, is to sanitise the JSON in the Python import to skip those keys